# Session doesnt exist in current context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Having trouble trying to implement a session it says it doesnt exist in the current context am i missing something?

```
 protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        //database connection string
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=x; Password=x; OPTION=3;");
        cn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from User where username=? and password=?", cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //Select the username and password from mysql database 

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = this.Login1.UserName;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = this.Login1.Password;
        //use asp login control to check username and password

        //Session["UserID"] = "usrName";
        //set the UserID from the User Table unsure how to add this to the sql syntax above

        OdbcDataReader dr = default(OdbcDataReader);
        // Initialise a reader to read the rows from the login table.  
        // If row exists, the login is successful  

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        DataRow dp = dt.Rows[0];

        OdbcDataAdapter adp = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
        { 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        adp.Fill(dt); 
        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0) 
        { 
            Session("UserID") = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["UserID"]);
            e.Authenticated = true; 
            Response.Redirect("UserProfileWall.aspx"); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it seems to think you're accessing the `Session` object as a method. You need to have:

```
Session["UserID"] = dp["UserID"].ToString();
```

Comment: how do i retrieve this on another aspx page?

Comment: @Garrith Graham: If you mean how do you access the session variable in another web page after this has been done you would use: `if(Session["UserID"] != null) { string userID = Session["UserID"].ToString(); }`

Comment: @Garrith you need to use an OdbcDataAdapter to fill your DataTable. Try this: using (OdbcDataAdapter adp = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd))
  {
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   adp.Fill(dt);

   if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
   {
    Session("UserID") = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["UserID"]);
    e.Authenticated = true;
    Response.Redirect("UserProfileWall.aspx");
   }
  }

Comment: sorry hopdizzle could you post that as an answer? Im getting a few errors?

Answer (score 6):

It should be

```
Session["UserID"] = Convert.ToString(dp["UserID"]);
```

You need to use square brackets

Comment: Haha, I saw that. You could argue that dp["UserID"].ToString() is more correct though

Comment: I could, but I'm not really that picky.